# Reset badge on app icon from push

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I use parse to send pushes to iOS and Android users. For some reason after Parse interface update the default setting "Increment the app badge?" was enabled and all iOS users now see red badge with "1".

In my current app version. I don't have any code in my app that deletes badges.
How can i reset this badge for my users? Maybe i can send some push to set it number to equal 0?

Comment: yes, a push with `0` could help.

Comment: how it can be done? for example from parse.com interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of choose `text` you should click on `JSON`

Something like that:

[image]

> For each notification, compose a JSON dictionary object (as defined by
>   RFC 4627). This dictionary must contain another dictionary identified
>   by the key aps. The aps dictionary can contain one or more properties
>   that specify the following user notification types:
>
> An alert message to display to the user 
>   A number to badge the app icon with 
>   A sound to play

From here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Also you could use `"content-available" : 1` to create a silent Push Notification, that the users will receive the push but won't notify then, so you can just send this push to erase the badge

Comment: It is good solution! Thank you! I found out that for silent push it is necessary to send JSON without "alert"

Answer (score 0):

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
  let inst = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
  if inst.badge != 0{
    inst.badge = 0
    inst.saveEventually()
  }
}
```

If you want to do that without updating the app you can send Push through Parse website and set `badge : 0`.

Comment: i can add it only it new version of app - but it will be available in about a week - i want to reset it now)

Comment: Send then push with `badge : 0`